# Cant recognize class in webform project

Tags: c#, webforms

In my web form project I opened a folder called App_Code inside that folder I have class named `Test123`, but when I try to create instance inside `WebForm1.aspx.cs` it doesn't recognize that type

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace StephanProject_2.App_Code
{
    public class Test123
    {
    }
}
```

My project structure:

[image]

I tried to add `using StephanProject_2.App_Code;`

What's the problem?

Comment: Please show the code of the Test123 class.
I think it has somthing to do with the class modifier

Answer (score 1):

The class you are calling does not seem to be in the same namespace as the Webform1 class

if its from another namespace use.

```
StephanProject_2.App_Code.Test123 t = new StephanProject_2.App_Code.Test123()
```

Or alternatively in the top say

```
using StephanProject_2.App_Code;
```

Comment: In my post I wrote I tried `using StephanProject_2.App_Code;` this does'nt work, I think this is the line `_`

Comment: What happens if you try specifying the namespace with the class like this? StephanProject_2.App_Code.Test123 t = new StephanProject_2.App_Code.Test123()

Comment: The underline was the problem

Answer (score -1):

When i try to same as your project then it works my code 
You can see [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkwrg.jpg)

Comment: That's asp.net project not console app

Comment: When i try to same as your project then it works my code